# How can I use standard 2.0 Entity Framework Library with a NET 5 project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0

I have .net framework 4.8 and a NET 5 projects that I both wants to use a netstandard 2.0 library with Entity Framework.

standard 2.0 references, the latest version that works:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6">
```

NET 5 references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7">
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.7" />
```

The NET 5 project references the netstandard 2.0 library

I can then scaffold using just the basic scaffold params

> Scaffold-DbContext "Data
> Source=SQLSERVER2019.xyz.local;Database=FlexEF;Trusted_Connection=True"
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

But my context class is then full of errors like:

Error   CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Error   CS1061  'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasNoKey' and no accessible extension method 'HasNoKey' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS1061  'PropertyBuilder<short?>' does not contain a definition for 'HasComment' and no accessible extension method 'HasComment' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyBuilder<short?>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: I am not sure if I miss something, but aren't those totally different versions? - and hence - have a different API?

Comment: Stefan if you read this paragraph here: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/ef/core/cli/powershell#other-target-frameworks

It leads me to believe that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that in my context I only need to have this one using

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

In NET5 I only need to reference the 3 packages, in Standard2.0 I need to add a lot more packages, that apparently belongs to the same namespace.

Such as:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

etc etc.

Sigh...